# Multi-Select as an Available Filter in a Saved Search

Tags: netsuite

I checked SuiteAnswers and here on Stack overflow but don't see an answer. Is there a way to make a Multi-select field in NetSuite as an option for an available filter in a Saved Search. I tried to do this by creating a test MS field on an Employee and creating a saved search. However, when adding it as an available filter it grays out the ability to show in the filter region, which, by all practical purposes, makes it not usable as an available filter.

Has anyone found a way to do this? Or do I have to have multiple searches for variations on the values we want in the multi-select, which is not ideal?

Comment: We are experiencing a similar issue, I've posted a similar question on NetSuite's User Community -- https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/forum/platform-areas/customization/searches-list-views/430711-using-a-multi-select-field-in-view-filter-region

Answer (score 0):

This is very frustrating NetSuite behaviour however I have found a workaround that works **some** of the time.

1. Create a saved search
2. Go to the "Available Filters" subtab
3. Add the Select/List type field(s) you require
4. Tick "Show In Filter Region."
   At this point the "Show as multi-select" checkbox will be greyed out (disabled.)
5. Save and run the search.
6. Click "Edit This Search"
7. Navigate back to the "Available Filters" subtab and the "Show As
   Multi-select" checkbox should now be enabled, tick it.
8. Save and run your search again.